# Copy row name that has multiple rows of data under it without that name into new column for each row under that row name

Tags: excel, vba

[Example of what I'm working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Py1uT.jpg)

I get this worksheet, shown in the link above, every month with thousands of rows. You can see row 11, 16, 21, and 26 have Blue text. I want to make a VBA macro that will copy the name of B11 into A12:A15, B16 into A17:A20 and so on. Any ideas? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Welcome to SO ;) Please read this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This would include a proper description of what you are trying to achieve, your code (or the relevant snippets) as well as your efforts showing what you have tried so far and possible error messages. It is also advisable to provide a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)..

Comment: Was the main issue that I started the question with the word So? Is my description of what I want to achieve not explicit enough? I'm not asking these questions to be difficult, I just want to better understand what your main issues with my posting are. I've read the links you posted. Also, I'm a novice with VBA and have pretty much no idea how to write VBA code. I asked this question to see if anyone would be willing to help me write a code that would achieve what I want. If questions like this are not welcome here then I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you started...also look into creating range objects and using For Each so you don't have to physically select cells (this way was just quicker to compose):

```
Sub NameToLeft()
    Dim roomName As String
    Range("B1").Select
    While Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row) <> ""
        If Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255) Then
            roomName = Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row)
        Else
            With Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row)
              .Value = roomName
              .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
            End With
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: And I don't know you're exact color...you can determine your RGB code by going to the color chooser and selecting "...more colors."

Comment: This method also assumes that you have no gaps in your data. You can use range("B100000").End(xlUp).row to find the last row of your data and change your while statement to go until that row is reached.

Comment: Some people prefer other techniques to find the last row [link](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba) ... the one I suggested is just the one I'm used to using.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked like a charm. I really appreciate you offering your time and expertise to help me out.